# How to work with rails render with ajax javascript request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have action in controller

```
def login
    @message = params[:mess]
    @user = 1
    render :rend_log_form
end
```

the view - rend_log_form.js.erb

```
l = $("#log_form");
console.log(<%= @message %>);
l.html("<%= j(render(partial: 'login/log_form', locals: {user: @user})) %>");
```

and some javascript code

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/login",
       data: {mess:"eee"}, 
       success:function(data) {
         console.log("SUCCESS POST");
         console.log(data);
       },
       error:function(data) {
         console.log("ERROR POST:"); 
         console.log(data);
       }
    });
```

action and controller works ok if use link_to with remote: true, but with my javascript code I have in browser console:

```
ERROR POST:
Object
```

the Object.responseText - the code of rend_log_form.js.erb

How to render the form with javascript?

Comment: Try adding `dataType : "html"` in your ajax request.

Comment: @HarryBomrah BIG THANKS, it helps to see the SUCCESS POST. I also add `globalEval(data)` . `function globalEval(code) {   window.execScript ? execScript(code) : window.eval(code);
}`

Comment: Glad could help :)

Comment: `eval` is not safe to use.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to Hary Bomrah, adding `dataType:"html"` to ajax call in js code has helped.